# Swagger doesn't display information about methods - SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I have an API in Java SpringBoot and I want to document it in Swagger.

I have done the following (I only include classes that contain some code related to Swagger):

**Main class**

```
@EnableSwagger2
public class ProvisioningApiApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (AuthConfigFactory.getFactory() == null) {
        AuthConfigFactory.setFactory(new AuthConfigFactoryImpl());
    }
    SpringApplication.run(ProvisioningApiApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public Docket swaggerSpringMvcPluggin() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
            .build();
}

@Component
@Primary
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    }
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Provisioning API")
            .version("0.0.1")
            .build();
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@CrossOrigin
public class RecursoController {

@Autowired
private Configuration configuration;
@Autowired
private TypeSpecService typeSpecService;
@Autowired
private IoTAgentService ioTAgentService;
@Autowired
private OrionService orionService;
@Autowired
private DeviceIdService deviceIdService;

@ApiOperation(value = "Put a device", nickname = "provisionDevice", tags = "Device")
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Ok", response = NewDeviceResponse.class)
})
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/devices", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<NewDeviceResponse> provisionDevice(@RequestBody NewDeviceRequest newDeviceRequest,
                                                         @RequestHeader("X-Auth-Token") String oAuthToken) {
    // what my method does
}
```

The documentation results in the following `swagger.json` file:

```
{
    swagger: "2.0",
    info: {
        version: "0.0.1",
        title: "Provisioning API"
    },
    host: "localhost:8080",
    basePath: "/"
}
```

As you can see, it only contains the name and the version of API but not the `provisionDevice` method.

I've tried everything but I can't figure it out what I'm doing bad. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to add apis() to `APISelectorBuilder`:   `return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
...
            .select().apis("packagetoscan")
            .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
            .build();`

Comment: Yes, I tried it @jny but it doesn't work. The `swagger.json` output continues as I posted in my question. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add @Api annotation in your class, where you have your main services?